# What should be casted in the query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Pojo {

private int stopID;
private String stopCD;
private String stopName;
private String stopAlias1;
private String stopAlias2;
private String stopAlias3;
private String stopName_Reg_Lang1;
private String stopName_Reg_Lang2;
private String lastUpdatedBy;
private String delFlag;
private String createRoleID;
private String updateRoleID;
private String createUserID;
private String stopNameRoad;
private String audioFile;
private int stopTypeID;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private int radius;
private int latRounded1;
private int longRounded1;
private int latRounded2;
private int longRounded2;
private int latRounded3;
private int longRounded3;
private int jurisdiction;
private int districtID;
private int stateID;
private String mobile;
private int cityType;
private int fontType;
private int cityNameID;
private Date createTime;
private Date lastUpdatedTime;

//setters and getters
}
```

DAO CLASS METHOD

```
public JSONObject getSaveToDatabase(List dataHolder) throws ParseException {
List list= new ArrayList();
     Session sessionOracle=null;
     Pojo Db=new Pojo();
     sessionOracle=BaseDAO.getHibernateSession().openSession();
     org.hibernate.Transaction txOracle=null;

     //list contains record
     Db.setStopID((int)list.get(0));
     System.out.println(Db.getStopID());

     try{

         txOracle=sessionOracle.beginTransaction();
         System.out.println(sessionOracle.isOpen());
         sessionOracle.save(Db);
         txOracle.commit();
         System.out.println("Data is inserted");
          }catch(Exception i){
         txOracle.rollback();
         i.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("Exception in POI ------"+i.toString());
     }
```

And the exception:

```
Hibernate: insert into POI_M_STOP (stop_id, stop_name, stop_alias_name1, stop_alias_name2, stop_alias_name3, stop_cd, stop_type_id, jurisdiction, mobile_number, del_flag, create_user_id, latitude, longitude, create_time, last_updated_time, district_id, state_id, lat_rounded, lat_rounded_2, lat_rounded_3, long_rounded, long_rounded_2, long_rounded_3, audio_file, stop_name_road, city_type, city_name_id, STOP_NAME_REG_LANG1, STOP_NAME_REG_LANG2, LAST_UPDATED_BY, CREATE_ROLE_ID, UPDATED_ROLE_ID, RADIUS_FOR_DETECTION, FONT_TYPE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

While I was working with above query without hibernate and by insert query in JDBC, the data is being inserted properly.
I am just checking with the id column and "session.save(obj)" and "transaction.commit();--line(1)".
At line (1) its throwing the above exception.
As "stop_id" is of type int in application and corresponding "id" in db is of type int.

XXXX.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="excel.apsrtc.pojo.Pojo" table="POI_M_STOP">
<id name="stopID" type="int">
<column name="stopID"></column>
</id>

<property name="stopName" type="java.lang.String" column="stop_name"></property>
    <property name="stopAlias1" type="java.lang.String" column="stop_alias_name1"></property>
    <property name="stopAlias2" type="java.lang.String" column="stop_alias_name2"></property>
    <property name="stopAlias3" type="java.lang.String" column="stop_alias_name3"></property>
    <property name="stopCD" type="java.lang.String" column="stop_cd"></property>
    <property name="stopTypeID" type="int"  column="stop_type_id"></property>
    <property name="jurisdiction" type="java.lang.String"  column="jurisdiction"></property>
    <property name="mobile" type="java.lang.String"  column="mobile_number"></property>
    <property name="delFlag" type="java.lang.String"  column="del_flag"></property>
    <property name="createUserID" type="java.lang.String"  column="create_user_id"></property>
    <property name="latitude" type="double"  column="latitude"></property>
    <property name="longitude" type="double"  column="longitude"></property>
    <property name="createTime" type="java.util.Date"><column name="create_time" /></property>
    <property name="lastUpdatedTime" type="java.util.Date"><column name="last_updated_time" /></property>
    <property name="districtID" type="int"  column="district_id"></property>
    <property name="stateID" type="int"  column="state_id"></property>
     <property name="latRounded1" type="int"  column="lat_rounded"></property>
    <property name="latRounded2" type="int"  column="lat_rounded_2"></property>
    <property name="latRounded3" type="int"  column="lat_rounded_3"></property>
    <property name="longRounded1" type="int"  column="long_rounded"></property>
    <property name="longRounded2" type="int"  column="long_rounded_2"></property>
    <property name="longRounded3" type="int"  column="long_rounded_3"></property>
    <property name="audioFile" type="java.lang.String"  column="audio_file"></property>
    <property name="stopNameRoad" type="java.lang.String"  column="stop_name_road"></property>
    <property name="cityType" type="int"  column="city_type"></property> 
    <property name="cityNameID" type="java.lang.String"  column="city_name_id"></property>
    <property name="stopName_Reg_Lang1" type="java.lang.String" column="STOP_NAME_REG_LANG1"></property>
    <property name="stopName_Reg_Lang2" type="java.lang.String" column="STOP_NAME_REG_LANG2"></property>
    <property name="lastUpdatedBy" type="java.lang.String" column="LAST_UPDATED_BY"></property>
    <property name="createRoleID" type="java.lang.String" column="CREATE_ROLE_ID"></property>
    <property name="updateRoleID" type="java.lang.String" column="UPDATED_ROLE_ID"></property>
    <property name="radius" type="java.lang.String" column="RADIUS_FOR_DETECTION"></property>
    <property name="fontType" type="java.lang.String" column="FONT_TYPE"></property>


</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

please help  me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the entity class?

Comment: And the code used to save it.

Comment: What is `excel2Db`? It's an object that surely is not instantiated in the method you posted.

Comment: You're not providing enough information. The error is definitely caused by a string-typed column/field. What makes you think that the seq_id field is the problem? It would be of great help to us if you provide your entire mapping file and your entire entity class.

Comment: As I was not passing or setting any value other than stop_id on 'Db' object and saving object 'Db' on OracleSession Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mismatches between your entity class and your mapping file, e.g. `fontType`/`FONT_TYPE`. The type of `fontType` field is `int`, while in hbm file it is mapped to `java.lang.String`.

Please look for any other similar mismatches and fix them. After that, you shouldn't get that error anymore.